# Shortcuts made on new command skip 'eat up' the space and the next few letters after itself

Tags: macros

In my report, the phrase "separated representation" is used very frequently. So, I created a macro

```
\newcommand{\seprep}[1]{separated representation}
```

However, when I use the command, it eats up the next few characters.

```
Such type of \sepreps are commonly
```

it generates the following output. Please note the missing "a" in "are".
[image]

Please let me know if there is a solution to this problem. Thank you.

Comment: This is expected as you defined a macro that takes one mandatory argument, you did not give it one and thus it eats up spaces and chars until it has found enough to qualify as an argument, in this case it eats the a

Comment: Solution, (1) your macro dies not use arguments, so use `[0]` or remove the argument specification. (2) macros do always eat up spaces so best to use `\seprep{} ` even if it does not take any arguments, this stops is from eating spaces. In general, fi you really save anything buy writing like this? Perhaps better to just adjust your editor to insert a user defined template, which will just be those words.

Comment: Your suggestion works. Thank you. I will look into how to use user-defined templates